# pandas insert only new values from one df to another with conditions

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

my pandas **dataframes** df1 and df2

df2 is empty **dataframe.**

df1:

| id | name | address | startdate | enddate | middate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | abc | 123st west drive | 01/31/2021 | null | 01/31/2021 |
| 1 | bcc | 23st east drive | 01/31/2021 | null | 01/31/2021 |
| 2 | abc | 24st orlando | 02/31/2021 | null | 02/31/2021 |
| 3 | ac | 2st coast rd | 01/31/2021 | null | 01/31/2021 |
| 4 | bcc | 23st east drive | 02/31/2021 | null | 02/31/2021 |

I want to insert df1 into df2 one by one based on name and address column,

1. if name already exists
2. need to check address
3. if same address then crunch the record by updating middate of previous by start of new record.
4. if different address update previous record
   then end and mid as start of new record

in our case
id 0 and 2 are having same names but different address
so the df2 should be like

df2:

| id | name | address | startdate | enddate | middate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | abc | 123st west drive | 01/31/2021 | 02/31/2021 | 02/31/2021 |
| 1 | abc | 24st orlando | 02/31/2021 | null | 02/31/2021 |
| 2 | bcc | 23st east drive | 01/31/2021 | null | 02/31/2021 |
| 3 | ac | 2st coast rd | 01/31/2021 | null | 01/31/2021 |

I used merge but not getting desired output. thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Could you add the code of what you have tried. Wrt rule 3, `bcc - 23st east drive` is the same name and address occurring twice - you've used `startdate` from the first occurrence but `middate` from the 2nd record. Is that intended?

Comment: yes if address is same the record should be crunched and midate should be updated as startdate of the new record.

Answer (score 1):

Using `groupby()`

- collapse **name** and **address**
- `groupby()` **name** to update **enddate** and **middate** to **startdate** of next row in the group

```
df1 = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""id name    address startdate   enddate middate
0   abc 123st west drive    01/31/2021  null    01/31/2021
1   bcc 23st east drive 01/31/2021  null    01/31/2021
2   abc 24st orlando    02/31/2021  null    02/31/2021
3   ac  2st coast rd    01/31/2021  null    01/31/2021
4   bcc 23st east drive 02/31/2021  null    02/31/2021"""), sep="\t")

# collapse the records
# collapse the records
df2 = df1.groupby(["name","address"], as_index=False).agg({"startdate":"first","enddate":"last","middate":"last"})

# update the dates
df2 = (df2.groupby(["name"])
 .apply(lambda dfa: dfa.assign(enddate=dfa.startdate.shift(-1),
                               middate=np.where(dfa.startdate.shift(-1).isna(),
                                                dfa.middate,
                                                dfa.startdate.shift(-1))))
 .reset_index(drop=True)
)
```

|  | name | address | id | startdate | enddate | middate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | abc | 123st west drive | 0 | 01/31/2021 | 02/31/2021 | 02/31/2021 |
| 1 | abc | 24st orlando | 2 | 02/31/2021 | nan | 02/31/2021 |
| 2 | ac | 2st coast rd | 3 | 01/31/2021 | nan | 01/31/2021 |
| 3 | bcc | 23st east drive | 4 | 02/31/2021 | nan | 02/31/2021 |

Comment: hi this doesnt work when the case like bcc first occuring record is less  i want to update only middate.in that case.

Comment: oh yes - have changed answer - initial build of **df2** changed to use combination of **first** and **last**

Comment: will it be smooth when using large dataset ?

Comment: think so - no for loops and pretty simple logic